# Make a script to call pager duty's API and update on call

Tags: python, pagerduty

I made this script it works, I'm just looking for ways to make it better/reading to get better.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests, logging, json, subprocess, re, smtplib
from datetime import datetime, date

# logger things
log_file = '/var/log/pagerduty.log'
## logging things
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(process)d-%(asctime)s-%(levelname)s-%(funcName)s %(message)s',
                    filename=log_file)
###
today = datetime.now()
api_key = '<removed>'
file_path = '<removed>'
# teams_webhook_url = <removed>'
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2",
    "Authorization": f"Token token={api_key}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

userInfo = {
    "Override": {
        "id": None,
        "name": None,
        "date_start": None,
        "date_end": None,
        "mobile": None,
        "turned_back": None
    },
    "onCall": {
        "id": None,
        "name": None,
        "date": None,
        "mobile": None,
    }
}

schedule_id = '<removed>'
start_time = today.replace(hour=0, minute=0)
end_time = today.replace(hour=23, minute=59)
print(start_time)

with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    oldFacts = json.load(file)

params = {
    'since': start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'),
    'until': end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
}
print(params)


# gets whos on call for real to get there mobile number
def whosOnCall():
    endpointoncall = f'https://api.pagerduty.com/schedules/{schedule_id}'
    responseOnCall = requests.get(endpointoncall, headers=headers, params=params)
    if responseOnCall.status_code == 200:
        oncallrawdata = responseOnCall.json()
        schedule_entries = oncallrawdata['schedule']['schedule_layers'][0]['rendered_schedule_entries']
        for facts in schedule_entries:
            logging.info(facts)
            userInfo['onCall']['id'] = facts['user']['id']
            userInfo['onCall']['name'] = facts['user']['summary']
            break
    else:
        logging.info(f"Failed to fetch overrides. Status code: {responseOnCall.status_code}")
        logging.info(responseOnCall.text)
        message = {"text": "Failed to fetch overrides. Status code: " + str(responseOnCall.status_code) + " "}
        # teamsMessage(message)


# gett the overrides and userID to get the number later
def userid():
    endpointOverrides = f'https://api.pagerduty.com/schedules/{schedule_id}/overrides'
    response = requests.get(endpointOverrides, headers=headers, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        overrides_data = response.json()
        overrides = overrides_data['overrides']
        if not overrides:
            logging.info(f"no call  forwarded needed")
            return False
        else:
            # returns a list of dics for overrides
            for override in overrides:
                save_override_info(override)
                return True
    else:
        logging.info(f"Failed to fetch overrides. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        logging.info(response.text)
        message = {"text": "Failed to fetch overrides. Status code: " + str({response.status_code}) + "  "}
        # teamsMessage(message)


def save_override_info(override):
    date_start = str(override['start'])
    date_end = str(override['end'])
    userInfo['Override']['id'] = override['user']['id']
    userInfo['Override']['date_start'] = date_start[:16]
    userInfo['Override']['date_end'] = date_end[:16]
    userInfo['Override']['name'] = override['user']['summary']
    logging.info(f" this is the info override found {userInfo}")
    return True


# puts the number from pager duty
def phonenumber(userID, whatType):
    endpointMobileNumber = f"https://api.pagerduty.com/users/{userID}/contact_methods/"
    responseMobile = requests.get(endpointMobileNumber, headers=headers)
    if responseMobile.status_code == 200:
        mobileData = responseMobile.json()
        for contactMethod in mobileData['contact_methods']:
            if contactMethod['type'] == 'phone_contact_method':
                userInfo[whatType]['mobile'] = checknumber(contactMethod['address'])
            elif contactMethod['type'] == 'email_contact_method':
                userInfo[whatType]['email'] = contactMethod['address']
    else:
        logging.info(f"Failed to fetch overrides. Status code: {responseMobile.status_code}")
        message = {"text": "Failed to fetch overrides. Status code: " + str(responseMobile.status_code) + " "}
        # teamsMessage(message)
        logging.info(responseMobile.text)


## email soooooon
def emails(whattype, to, number, overname, output):
    sender = '<removed>'
    try:
        if whattype in ['Override', 'onCall_return']:
            message_subject = 'Whoah man, you\'re  on call'
            message_body = {
                f'! \n\n Call forward for on call number <removed> has been set to your mobile {number} '
                f'{output}'}
        else:
            message_subject = "Whoah man, override found you  "
            message_body = {f'You are not on call  ! \n\n Call forward for on call number <removed> has been '
                            f'set to {overname} person {output}'}
        message = f'From: On Call<{sender}>\nTo: To Person {to}\nSubject: {message_subject}\n\n{message_body}'
        message_utf = message.encode('utf-8')
        session = smtplib.SMTP(<removed>')
        session.sendmail(sender, '<removed>'', message_utf)
        logging.info(f'Successfully sent email to {to}')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(f"Error: unable to send email {e}")


# def teamsMessage(message):
#    response = requests.post(teams_webhook_url, json=message)
#    if response.status_code == 200:
#        logging.info("Message as been sent")
#    else:
#        logging.info(f"Failed to send message. status code {response.status_code}")


# forwarding the on call 0800 number
def forwardNumbers(number):
    try:
        cmd = ["/usr/local/bin/updateoncallforward", number]
        run = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        stdout, stderr = run.communicate()
        stdout_without_password = re.sub(r'"password": ".*?"', '"password": "********"', stdout)
        logging.info(f"Subprocess Output: {stdout_without_password}")
        return stdout_without_password
    except FileNotFoundError:
        message = {"text": "updateoncallforward executable not found. help me SOS "}
        # teamsMessage(message)
        logging.info("updateoncallforward executable not found. ")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        message = {"text": "python call forward script exited with non-zero exit code: " + str(e.returncode) + ""}
        # teamsMessage(message)
        logging.info(f"updateoncallforward script exited with non-zero exit code: {e.returncode}")


# checks the number from pager duty as the numbers starts without the starting 0 adds that to the number
def checknumber(phone_number):
    pattern = r'^02\d{9}|02\d{8}$'
    if not str(phone_number).startswith('0'):
        phone_number = '0' + phone_number
    if re.match(pattern, phone_number):
        return phone_number
    else:
        logging.info(f"somthing is wrong with the phone number the number is question is {phone_number}")
        message = {"text": "somthing is wrong with the phone number the number is question is {phone_number}"}
        # teamsMessage(message)


def main():
    whosOnCall()
    output = ""
    current_server_time = datetime.now()
    start_time =  current_server_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
    print(start_time)
    override_needed = userid()
    if start_time == userInfo['Override']['date_start']:
        if override_needed is True and (oldFacts['Override']['turned_back'] == 0 or oldFacts['Override']['name']
                                        != userInfo['Override']['name']):
            for dic in userInfo:
                phonenumber(userInfo[dic]['id'], dic)
            output = forwardNumbers(userInfo['Override']['mobile'])
            for emailsAddresses in userInfo:
                if emailsAddresses == "Override":
                    emails(emailsAddresses, userInfo[emailsAddresses]['email'], userInfo[emailsAddresses]['mobile'],
                           userInfo[emailsAddresses]['name'], output)
                else:
                    emails(emailsAddresses, '<removed>'', userInfo[emailsAddresses]['mobile'],
                           userInfo[emailsAddresses]['name'], output)
            emails('onCall', userInfo['onCall']['email'], userInfo['Override']['mobile'],
                   userInfo['Override']['name'], output)
            message = {"text": "override found for today forwarded on call number from " + str(userInfo['onCall']['name'])
                               + "to " + str(userInfo['Override']['name']) + str(output)}
            #teamsMessage(message)
            userInfo['Override']['turned_back'] = 1
            with open(file_path, 'w') as file_override:
                json.dump(userInfo, file_override, indent=4)
    elif (
            override_needed is False
            and oldFacts['Override']['turned_back'] == 1
            and start_time == oldFacts['Override']['date_end']
    ):
        output = forwardNumbers(oldFacts['onCall']['mobile'])
        for emailsAddresses in oldFacts:
            if emailsAddresses == "Override":
                emails(emailsAddresses, oldFacts[emailsAddresses]['email'], oldFacts[emailsAddresses]['mobile'],
                       oldFacts[emailsAddresses]['name'], output)
            else:
                emails(emailsAddresses, '<removed>', oldFacts[emailsAddresses]['mobile'],
                       oldFacts[emailsAddresses]['name'], output)

        #emails('Override_return', oldFacts['Override']['email'], oldFacts['Override']['mobile'],
        #       oldFacts['Override']['name'], output)
        #emails('onCall_return', oldFacts['onCall']['email'], oldFacts['Override']['mobile'],
        #       oldFacts['Override']['name'], output)
        message = {"text": "Override returned to " + str(oldFacts['onCall']['name']) + "that was taken over from " +
                           str(oldFacts['Override']['name']) + "  could we just double check this worked "}
        # teamsMessage(message)
        oldFacts['Override']['turned_back'] = 0
        with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(oldFacts, file, indent=4)
        logging.info(f"on call returned to  {oldFacts['onCall']['name']}")
    else:
        logging.info("nothing to be done")
    logging.info("-" * 60)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# alert help im lost
```

Also when it finds an override it runs a different script that updates the on call number on net, and also updates the offnet number, forwards the output of that script so you know it works.

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se] (and note all sites on the network have guidance on [ask]).

Comment: "I made this script, it works". No, it doesn't. You can make it better by removing the double quote that causes the error (and provokes the rest of the code to be interpreted as a string). Being able to actually run the code is a big improvement

Comment: oh ok sorry didn't know what one was a thing sorry

Comment: oh sorry I added that to remove personal details oops didn't see i fucked that up sorry

Comment: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)